# Does Oracle really offer any OCI demo/sample programs?

Tags: oracle10g, demo, oracle-call-interface

Oracle, says that there are some demo/sample programs for OCI.

In my case I'd like to find examples of using OCIConnectionPoolCreate().
There should be in a file called `cdemocp.c`, according to the documentation:
 http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14250/ociabdem.htm

But its far from clear what I should install to get these files?
I would have hoped I could download them from Oracle's own website. Seems not. Certainly no handy link from the above page.

I have a tried installing (onto windows):

- An Oracle 10g XE database server, no such source files
- Oracle client (sdk options on), no such source files
- searched within our linux installations -- where did I find the fabled \rdbms\demo\ folder which contains a few make files referring to the demo source files, the  but *no source files*. So running these makefiles fails.

Basically, no luck finding them.

If I google for `cdemocp.c` I find only:

- the typical multiple copies of Oracle's own documentation
- other people saying they cant find it.

( I finding using oracle's documentation is like lord of the rings, only a faint connection with reality, and probably too many words. I'm not enjoying it. )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK found the OCI demo files. It was a **serious** pain to find them.

From Oracle, get some "Companion Disk". Such as:

"Oracle Database 10g Companion CD Release 2" : [102010_win64_x64_companion.zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/10201winx64soft-090882.html)

For me all the various "Universal"  installers I tried crashed, or refused to run.
Even when run on the OS they were supposed to be run on. 
*But*, having expanded the installer you can just dig out .jar files.
These .jar file are really just .zip files with a diffident extension. This file:

`102010_win64_x64_companion\companion\Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.rdbms.companion\10.2.0.3.0\1\DataFiles\filegroup2.jar`

when extracted, contains all the OCI demo files I wanted under `rdbms/demo/`. Voilà.

( I list them here so anyone googling for them might find this page. )

cdemdpco.c cdemdpin.c cdemdpit.c cdemdplp.c  cdemdpno.c  cdemdpro.c  cdemdpss.c cdemo1.c cdemo2.c cdemo3.c cdemo4.c cdemo5.c cdemo81.c cdemo82.c cdemoanydata1.c cdemoanydata2.c cdemobj.c cdemocoll.c cdemocor.c cdemocor1.c cdemocp.c cdemocpproxy.c cdemodp.c cdemodp_lip.c cdemodr1.c cdemodr2.c cdemodr3.c cdemodsa.c cdemodsc.c cdemodt.c cdemoext.c cdemofil.c cdemofo.c cdemofor.c cdemoin1.c cdemoin2.c cdemoin3.c cdemol2l.c cdemolb.c cdemolb2.c cdemolbs.c cdemoplb.c cdemoqc.c cdemoqc2.c cdemorid.c cdemort.c cdemosc.c cdemoses.c cdemosp.c cdemostc.c cdemosyev.c cdemothr.c cdemoucb.c cdemoucbl.c cdemouni.c cdemoup1.c cdemoup2.c cdemoupk.c cdemoxml.c extdemo2.c extdemo4.c extdemo5.c extdemo6.c nchdemo1.c obndra.c oci02.c oci03.c oci04.c oci05.c oci06.c oci07.c oci08.c oci09.c oci10.c oci11.c oci12.c oci13.c oci14.c oci15.c oci16.c oci17.c oci18.c oci19.c oci20.c oci21.c oci22.c oci23.c oci24.c oci25.c ociaqarraydeq.c ociaqarrayenq.c ociaqdemo00.c ociaqdemo01.c ociaqdemo02.c ociucb.c readpipe.c strmmon.c 
cdemo6.h cdemo82.h cdemobj.h cdemocoll.h cdemocor.h cdemodp.h cdemodp0.h cdemodr1.h cdemodr2.h cdemodr3.h cdemodsc.h cdemoin1.h cdemoin2.h cdemoin3.h cdemolb.h cdemorid.h cdemort.h cdemoses.h cdemosp.h cdemostc.h cdemothr.h extdemo2.h extdemo4.h extdemo5.h extdemo6.h mdemo1.h mymdemo1.h cdemo6.cc mdemo1.cpp mdemo1o.cpp occiaqlis.cpp occiaqop.cpp occiblob.cpp occiclob.cpp occicoll.cpp occidesc.cpp occidml.cpp occiinh.cpp occilbar.cpp occimb1.cpp occiobj.cpp occipobj.cpp occipool.cpp occiproc.cpp occiscp.cpp occistre.cpp occiuni1.cpp occiuni2.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Update from above since some links changed

First download:

http://download.oracle.com/otn/linux/oracle11g/R2/linux.x64_11gR2_examples.zip

Then if you have 7zip on windows you can drill down to the zip and jar file like this:

Downloads\linux.x64_11gR2_examples.zip\examples\stage\Components\oracle.rdbms.companion\11.2.0.1.0\1\DataFiles\filegroup2.jar\rdbms\demo\

Answer (score 1):

After struggling to find the OCI sample programs for Oracle 12 on Windows, I found them here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-win64-download-2297732.html

You need to log onto oracle and on the windows item, click "see all"

Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit)  File 1, File 2  (2.5 GB)  **See All**

**Oracle Database Examples** (12.1.0.2.0) for Microsoft Windows (x64)
    Download    winx64_12102_examples.zip (576,214,828 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

They are also available here -> https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/oci/oci.htm

Download ocilab.zip